# Simple stack based interpreter, C# style

Tags: c#

I wanted to see how simple it would be to implement a stack-based interpreter in C# based on this question: [Simple stack based interpreter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270065/simple-stack-based-interpreter)

The program works with the command line arguments which can either be a `double` or a function from the following table:

| instruction | op1 | op2 | op3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abs | a |  |  |
| acos | a |  |  |
| acosh | a |  |  |
| add | a | b |  |
| asin | a |  |  |
| asinh | a |  |  |
| atan | a |  |  |
| atan2 | a | b |  |
| atanh | a |  |  |
| bitdecrement | a |  |  |
| bitincrement | a |  |  |
| cbrt | a |  |  |
| ceiling | a |  |  |
| clamp | a | b | c |
| copysign | a | b |  |
| cos | a |  |  |
| cosh | a |  |  |
| div | a | b |  |
| exp | a |  |  |
| floor | a |  |  |
| fusedmultiplyadd | a | b | c |
| ieeeremainder | a | b |  |
| log | a | b |  |
| log10 | a |  |  |
| log2 | a |  |  |
| max | a | b |  |
| maxmagnitude | a | b |  |
| min | a | b |  |
| minmagnitude | a | b |  |
| mul | a | b |  |
| pow | a | b |  |
| round | a |  |  |
| sin | a |  |  |
| sinh | a |  |  |
| sqrt | a |  |  |
| sub | a | b |  |
| tan | a |  |  |
| tanh | a |  |  |
| truncate | a |  |  |

Example programs:

hypot: expected result: 5

```python
4 2 pow 3 2 pow add sqrt
```

After having some fun with `Reflection` and `Linq` I came up with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackProg
{
    class SimpleMath
    {
        public static double add(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
        public static double sub(double a, double b) { return a - b; }
        public static double mul(double a, double b) { return a * b; }
        public static double div(double a, double b) { return a / b; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var methods = new SortedDictionary<string, Tuple<int, MethodInfo>>();
            foreach (var type in new Type[] {typeof(SimpleMath), typeof(Math)})
            {
                foreach (var method in type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(double)))
                {
                    var margs = method.GetParameters();
                    if (margs.Any(p => p.ParameterType != typeof(double)) == false)
                        methods[method.Name.ToLower()] = new Tuple<int, MethodInfo>(margs.Length, method);
                }
            }

            var stack = new Stack<double>();
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(arg, out var val))
                {
                    stack.Push(val);
                }
                else if (methods.TryGetValue(arg, out var method))
                {
                    stack.Push((double)method.Item2.Invoke(null, PopStack(stack, method.Item1)));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid instruction: " + arg);
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.Write(stack.Pop());
        }

        private static object[] PopStack(Stack<double> stack, int count)
        {
            var list = new List<object>(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                list.Insert(0, stack.Pop());
            return list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use [ValueTuple with named fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) to increase readability. `Item1` and `Item2` are not really coder friendly names

Comment: Also in case of `PopStack` you know the `count` so you can create an array with the specified length and you don't have to use an intermediate List collection.

Comment: @PeterCsala, Thanks for the nice tips! `PopStack` sort of bugged me. I considered using a `ConcurrentStack` which has `TryPopRange` but that looked ugly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `PopStack`

- This can be rewritten like this using LINQ:

```
private static object[] PopStack(Stack<double> stack, int count)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(_ => stack.Pop()).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

#### `SimpleMath`

- This class can be marked as `static` since all of its members are `static`
- This class looks a bit weird/odd to me

  - You have defined a class just to expose built-in operators
  - The methods' naming do not follow C# standards
- My alternative solution relies on lambda expressions:

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>> simpleMath = new()
{
    { "add", (a, b) => a + b },
    { "sub", (a, b) => a - b },
    { "mul", (a, b) => a * b },
    { "div", (a, b) => a / b },
};
```

- Yes I know, the `simpleMath`'s type is ugly as hell

  - But we have avoided to repeat this: `public static double (double , double ) { return ; }`
  - Here the naming can be arbitrary, it does not have to follow any standard
- Because these methods are not `static` that's why they need an *invocation target* as well.

  - So, we need to store that information next to the name and method info
  - I've defined a `record` structure for that

```
record MethodInvocation(int ParameterCount, MethodInfo Method, object Target)
{
}
```

- Finally let's transform the `simpleMath` to the desired form

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MethodInvocation>> GetSimpleMath()
{
    foreach (var operation in simpleMath)
    {
        var mi = operation.Value.Method;
        yield return new (operation.Key, new MethodInvocation(mi.GetParameters().Length, mi, operation.Value.Target));
    }
}
```

#### AdvancedMath

- Following the same pattern as above we can do the same with the built-in methods:

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MethodInvocation>> GetAdvancedMath()
{
    foreach (var method in typeof(Math).GetMethods().Where(m => m.ReturnType == typeof(double)))
    {
        var @params = method.GetParameters();
        if (@params.Any(p => p.ParameterType != typeof(double)) is not true)
            yield return new (method.Name.ToLower(), new MethodInvocation(@params.Length, method, null));
    }
}
```

#### Main

- With these in our hand we can simplify the first part of the `Main` method like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var methods = new SortedDictionary<string, MethodInvocation>();

    foreach (var operation in GetSimpleMath())
        methods.Add(operation.Key, operation.Value);

    foreach (var operation in GetAdvancedMath())
        methods.TryAdd(operation.Key, operation.Value);

    var operationStack = new Stack<double>();
            
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(arg, out var val))
        {
            operationStack.Push(val);
        }
        else if (methods.TryGetValue(arg, out var method))
        {
            var @params = PopStack(operationStack, method.ParameterCount);
            var result = (double)method.Method.Invoke(method.Target, @params);
            operationStack.Push(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid instruction: " + arg);
            return;
        }
    }
    Console.Write(operationStack.Pop());
}
```